# Two NIC's in the same ip segment

Tags: linux, linux-networking, arp

**What is the best technical solution to solve this?**

I have a /24-segment with two NIC's in one Linux Server
(lets call it `srv`) that have two IP-addresses in this segment.

- NIC1 / eth0 / `10.10.1.101` / MAC1
- NIC2 / eth1 / `10.10.1.102` / MAC2

The segment `10.10.1.0 /24` links up
through a switch that allows access
trough it based on MAC/IP combination,
the IP is set by DHCP by this switch
(based on individual MAC).

So far, this *seems* to work - **somehow**. I know,
this setup is technically **not o.k.** and a look
into `/var/log/messages` shows the expected collisions
(Martian source packages) on `eth1` each 500ms:

```
...
srv kernel: [ 1217.220559] martian source 10.10.1.254 from 10.10.1.112, on dev eth1
srv kernel: [ 1217.220563] ll header: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:1e:68:9d:54:05:08:06
srv kernel: [ 1218.313186] martian source 10.10.1.255 from 10.10.1.59, on dev eth1
srv kernel: [ 1218.313190] ll header: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:13:d4:b7:6f:e9:08:00
...
```

Each NIC serves for its specific duties (connected to different web sites served by one apache2 server in ip-based vhosts-setup).

**How to solve this?** I know (and I did actually), one may switch off the 'martian packet logging' by the usual `sysctrl -p` calls:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.log_martians = 0
```

but the problem should be solveable in a clean way? Or isn't?

Regards & Thanks

rbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually need 2 nics?

A way round this could be to add an alias to one of the interfaces to assign the additional IP address:

sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0:1 10.10.1.102/24 up

Comment: this would prevent packets from the interface (IP/MAC) from going upstream trought the router. **BUT**, probably it's not even necessary to have uplink on this interface (I'll check this). Thanks!